# Power series summing $e^{-n + i n^2}$ over positive integers

Tags: power-series, exponential-function, special-functions

Consider the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{- \alpha n +i\beta n^2}$

with $\beta$ a real number, and $\alpha$ a complex number with positive real part, so the series converges absolutely. Is this series related to any special function, or, more open-endedly, can it be simplified to a closed-form expression that is not an infinite series?

Comment: looks geometric series

Comment: @ILoveMath it is not a geometric series, because of the n^2 term in the exponent.

Comment: that why i says it look like

Comment: This is the incomplete theta function. Only the complete theta function (with $\Re(i\beta) < 0$) is considered a special function because special function means complicated with a lot of unexpected non-trivial properties

Comment: I am aware of the name of the function. But having scanned through the literature on incomplete theta functions, I did not find any practical method of computation, beyond numerically summing each exponential term up to a cutoff. I would be glad to hear of any possible simplifications to the computation.

Comment: There is no simplification, that's the point of saying 'it is not a special function'